Do UWP Apps have a Windows product key?
I am currently developing an UWP app and I want to register an uninstall routine for it using the registry editor from windows.
I saw that I need to register the routine using the product key of the application.
So I wanted to ask, do uwp apps have windows product key and how can I set the key?
Thank you very much for your help!

When you build (install) a UWP app it winds up on the Start Menu. The (right click) context menu for that item includes an "Uninstall".

you don't need to implement an uninstall routine. UWP apps can be easily removed via "installed apps" by default

UWP doesn't have a Windows product key. UWP apps are primarily distributed through the Microsoft Store. When a user installs an app from the Store, the licensing information is managed by the Store itself.
